# How to test angular observable with forkjoin?

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, karma-jasmine, angular-test, karma-coverage

Is there a way to mock switchMap and forkJoin on Karma Test?

```ts
this.session.userStream.pipe(
  take(1),

  switchMap(user => forkJoin([
    this.http.get<IUser>(`/users/${user.id}`),
    this.http.get<ICardProgram>(`/users/${user.id}/card-program`)
  ])),

  finalize(() => {
    this.isLoading = false;
  })
)
```

Comment: You typically don't replace operators with mocks. You can mock source Observables however.

Comment: I would create API service with two methods geUser and getUserProgram, then injected into current service/component, then you can easily mock userstream observable and two methods from API service, we  don't need to mock rxJs operators, then just subscribe and verify output data

Comment: you can rely on these libraries to be well tested and do exactly what you want them to. The thing you would most likely want to "mock" are your http calls. That is where `spies` come into play within jasmine.